# Splatmap for terrain in SceneKit

Tags: swift, terrain, scenekit

I am working on the terrain for a simple SceneKit game and am trying to apply different materials to the same mesh for a splat map effect. The terrain is procedurally generated so I can't model it out in Collada and load it in with the textures applied.

It seems the common way among other game engines to apply materials/textures to terrain is to use a splat map. SceneKit doesn't seem to have that construct or simple way for doing terrain.

What I have tried was to procedurally generate a transparency map for different textures/colors and then add those materials to the geometry something like...

```
    var alphaMaps = [NSBitmapImageRep]()
    for x in 0..<4{
        alphaMaps.append(createBitmapImage()!)
    }

    var x = 0
    var y = 0

    let waterLevel = 0
    let snowLevel = 241
    let mountainLevel = 200

    for tile in self.map.sortedTiles{
        let height = Int(tile.height)
        println("Height\(height)")
        var onLevel = -1
        if height < waterLevel{
            onLevel = 0
        }
        ...
        for i in 0..<4{
            var color = NSColor(deviceRed: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: i == onLevel ? 0 : 1)
            alphaMaps[i].setColor(color, atX: x, y: y)
        }
        ... generate the geometry
     }
    var materials = [SCNMaterial]()
    for h in 0..<4{
        let mat = SCNMaterial()
        switch( h){
        case 0:
            mat.diffuse.contents = NSColor.blueColor()
        case 1:
            mat.diffuse.contents = NSColor.greenColor()
        case 2:
            mat.diffuse.contents = NSColor.brownColor()
        case 3:
            mat.diffuse.contents = NSColor.whiteColor()
        default:
            println("FAIL")
        }

        mat.transparent.contents = alphaMaps[h].CGImage
        materials.append(mat)
    }

    geometry.materials = materials
```

I have verified that the alpha maps are correct but they don't seem to be respected. Only the first material is being used and it isn't using the transparent image.

Here is an example of the alpha map, the non black portion is transparent:
[image: Simple Alpha Map]

Is there a way to do a splat map in SceneKit? Or pointers on how to fix whats going on? Do I need to delve into a custom shader?

Comment: You probably need to look into custom shaders, or more likely just shader modifiers. It will be hard to assign a completely new material, but it should be fairly easy to change a material property or two (for example diffuse, specular, or normal).

Comment: However, I'm not sure what exactly how much you are trying to change between the different materials, or how many different configurations you are trying to use on the same element.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem was incorrect texture coordinates. and then having to duplicate the geometry to multiple nodes and apply the separate material to each node. I'm not happy with how it all works as it is forcing me to quadruple the verts loaded. I'm going to look into a different way of doing it.